# Why is my local host unable to rediect to other pages?

Tags: php, html

I have a following php code:I am at signin.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_POST['firstName']) && !isset($_POST['lastName']) && !isset($_POST['email']) && 
 !isset($_POST['password']) && !isset($_POST['confirmedPassword'])){
 $_SESSION['error']="Please Fill Out all the fields";
 header("Location:signin.php");
    return;
}
else{
if($_POST['password']!=$_POST['confirmedPassword']){
    $_SESSION['error']="Passwords don't match.Retry!!";
    header("Location:signin.php");
    return;
    }else{
       header("Location:index.php");
    return;
    }
  }
 ?>
```

In my html form I created a sign Up form which enables the users to sign in themselves. However when I run the  code my localhost says

```
localhost redirected you too many times.
 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Comment: Is the above code in `index.php` or `signin.php` ? If Yes there is some issue with your if conditions.

Comment: I am at signin.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting the user to the sign-in page if any of those five `$_POST[]` is empty. When you do a `GET` request `$_POST[]` would naturally be empty and hence you are stuck in an infinite loop. So before checking if those `$_POST[]` variables exist, you just check the request type too.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') //<--check request type
{
    if (empty($_POST['firstName']) || empty($_POST['lastName']) ||  empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['confirmedPassword']))
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Please Fill Out all the fields";
        header("Location:signin.php");
    }
    else
    {
        if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmedPassword'])
        {
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Passwords don't match.Retry!!";
            header("Location:signin.php");
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location:index.php");
        }
    }
}
exit;
?>
```

In addition:

- Replaced `empty()` in place of `!isset()`. It's better.
- It's should be `||` and not `&&`. You need to check if any of them are empty.
- Replaced `return` with `exit`. And moved the `exit` to the last line.

Comment: any difference between exit and return?

Comment: @The-coder I updated the answer to use `||` in place of `&&`. Also read: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php . Almost the same in this scenario, however `exit` is better from a global perspective and was exactly made for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to the sign in page. You will probably be stuck in an infinite loop where the post variables are never filled in (it's a get request). Thus redirecting too many times, where the browser will pick up on and stop the infinite loop.

Comment: didn't work even after i removed the entire else part

Comment: You also have an if part which checks the post variables on line 3. At what location is this PHP page located?

Comment: I am at signin.php

Comment: Well it seems Hackinet did the heavy lifting for you